# Error in rake path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I just created a new rails app in the RubyMine IDE and it tried to run rake but gave this error:

```
rubygems.rb:340:in 'bin_path': can't find executable rake for rake-0.8.7 <Gem::Exception>
              from C:\Ruby192\bin\rake:19:in '<main>'
```

I then got the same error when I tried to run it outside the IDE in a console.

Can't somebody help or offer some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the gem installed

```
gem list --local | grep rake
```

If not then

```
gem install rake
```

Comment: I've tried un-installing and re-installing but still the same message.